# %in% but looking similar strings R

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to search for what strings are similar in a column of a df in another df, for example in `df1` I have this:

```
nombres
Acesco Corporation
Exito S.A
AMI 
Renault
```

and in a `df2`I found this:

```
nombres
Acesco
Exito 
AMI 
Renault
```

I want a function similar to %in% that gives an output like this:
`Acesco, Exito, AMI`

Comment: You can use `grep` or `grepl` in R base, or `str_detect` in stringr

Comment: You need to define what constitutes a "hit" more precisely.  Would "`df2` string in `df1` string but not equal to `df1` string suffice?  If so, a simple combination of str_locate` (or `str_match`) and `==` will probably give you what you want.

Comment: Why are `nombres` and `Renault` excluded in your expected output? Is it because they are exactly in `df1`? If so, I think the rule is `txt2[grepl(paste(txt2, collapse = "|"), txt1) & !(txt2 %in% txt1)]`

Answer (score 0):

We can use:

```
txt1 <- c('nombres',
'Acesco Corporation',
'Exito S.A',
'AMI ',
'Renault')

txt2 <- c(
'nombres',
'Acesco',
'Exito',
'AMI',
'Renault')

dist_matrix <- data.frame(t(adist(txt1, txt2))) # columns correspond to txt1 after transposing
txt2[sapply(dist_matrix, which.min)]

[1] "nombres" "Acesco"  "Exito"   "AMI"     "Renault"
```

Where `adist` computes a distance between two strings.

> The (generalized) Levenshtein (or edit) distance between two strings s
> and t is the minimal possibly weighted number of insertions, deletions
> and substitutions needed to transform s into t

Answer (score 0):

I found a way that may work, not as good as the one from @gaut, but may work

```
lapply(df1, function(x) grep(x, df2))
```

This give the position where its foundable in df1, those that are in df2.

Hope helps!

Comment: I think this method makes more sense than that you accepted. @gaut's answer is to find the most similar string in `txt2` for each string in `txt1`. So, for example, `txt1 <- c('abc', 'def'); txt2 <- c('ghi', 'jkl', 'mno')`. These two vectors are entirely irrelevant but his method still gives outputs. Is it really what you want?

Comment: You are right, thats not the expected output. Maybe I want that the lapply function gives me the strings rather than the position, do you know a way of how to do it?. In that case, this one would be the correct answer. @DarrenTsai

Comment: note that this method will only work when one string contains exactly the other: `company SA` won't match with `Company S.A.`. That is the interest of the approximate (fuzzy) distances, on which you could impose a threshold to avoid non-relevant matches

Answer (score 0):

I would just extend @lasagna's answer by taking the diagonal of the matrix, and then binding it to the original data frame so it can be used in the next steps...

```
df<-dist_matrix %>% as.matrix()
mydists<-diag(df)
dist_matrix$mydist<-mydists
dist_matrix
```